# PostgreSQL: Customers preferred product and second most preferred product

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm pretty new to SQL (currently using PostgreSQL but interested in knowledge about any SQL), and am trying to figure something that I guess should be relatively straightforward.

I have a table containing one row per customer transaction, for each transaction I know what the customer bought. I am interested in finding out what product is each customers preferred choice, and then their second to most preferred choice (and in the end, on a general basis what is the preferred second choice when the preferred choice is unavailable).

Below is a mock up of what the data could look like:

```
+---------------------+-----------------+
| Customer_id         | Product bought  |
+---------------------+-----------------+
| 1                   |     DVD         |
+-                   -+-               -+
| 1                   |     DVD         |
+-                   -+-               -+
| 1                   |     Blu-ray     |
+-                   -+-               -+
| 1                   |     DVD         |
+-                   -+-               -+
| 2                   |     DVD         |
+-                   -+-               -+
| 2                   |     DVD         |
```

The successful results would be something like this:

```
+---------------------+--------------------------------+
| Customer_id         | Preferred #1    | Preferred #2 |
+---------------------+--------------------------------+
| 1                   |     DVD         |   Blu-ray    |
+-                   -+-               -+
| 2                   |     DVD         |   $NULL$     |
```

(And as mentioned earlier, the final result (most likely done in Python/R and not in SQL, would be to see a general basis as "If Preferred #1 is DVD, then Preferred #2 is Blu-ray", "If Preferred #1 is Blu-ray, then Preferred #2 is Sandwich"... and so on)

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a combination of a [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) and a [pivot](/questions/tagged/pivot) problem (sometimes also referred to as [crosstab](/questions/tagged/crosstab))

The first step you need to do is to identify the two preferred products.

In your case you need to combine a `group by` query with window functions.

The following query counts how often each customer has bought each product:

```
select customer_id, 
       product_bought,
       count(*) as num_products
from sales
group by customer_id, product_bought
order by customer_id;
```

This can be enhanced to include a rank for the number of times a product was bought:

```
select customer_id, 
       product_bought,
       count(*) as num_products,
       dense_rank() over (partition by customer_id order by count(*) desc) as rnk
from sales
group by customer_id, product_bought
order by customer_id;
```

This would return the following result (based on your sample data):

```
customer_id | product_bought | num_products | rnk
------------+----------------+--------------+----
          1 | DVD            |            3 |   1
          1 | Blu-ray        |            1 |   2
          2 | DVD            |            2 |   1
```

We cannot apply a where condition on the `rnk` column directly, so we need a derived table for that:

```
select customer_id, product_bought
from (
  select customer_id, 
         product_bought,
         count(*) as num_products,
         dense_rank() over (partition by customer_id order by count(*) desc) as rnk
  from sales
  group by customer_id, product_bought
) t
where rnk <= 2
order by customer_id;
```

Now we need to convert the two rows for each customer into columns. This could e.g. be done using a common table expression:

```
with preferred_products as (
  select *
  from (
    select customer_id, 
           product_bought,
           count(*) as num_products,
           dense_rank() over (partition by customer_id order by count(*) desc) as rnk
    from sales
    group by customer_id, product_bought
  ) t
  where rnk <= 2
)
select p1.customer_id, 
       p1.product_bought as "Product #1", 
       p2.product_bought as "Product #2"
from preferred_products p1 
  left join preferred_products p2 on p1.customer_id = p2.customer_id and p2.rnk = 2
where p1.rnk = 1
```

This then returns

```
customer_id | Product #1 | Product #2
------------+------------+-----------
          1 | DVD        | Blu-ray   
          2 | DVD        |
```

The above is standard SQL and will work on any modern DBMS.

Online example: http://rextester.com/VAID15638

Comment: Awesome, thanks this helped a lot and does everything I want to do (learned a lot too). Cheers.